# How to create a custom gradient with matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I already normalized my data to a colormap, I just dont know how to plot it. Here is the type of figure I want to create:

[image: sample]

I want to create something similar using the cmap 'bwr' where a value of '1' would be solid red and '0' would be solid blue. I used this to normalize my data and map it to the colors:

```
norm = Normalize(vmin = min(data), vmax = max(data), clip = True)
mapper = cm.ScalarMappable(norm = norm, cmap = plt.get_cmap('bwr'))
```

so the `data[0]` would be the far left of the figure and the last value in the list would be the far right.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Can you show the code where you try to plot anything? Because the code shown here is totally fine and should directly allow you to produce the desired plot.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest this is how I tried to plot it: `for i in range(len(data)):
    normaldata.append(norm(data[i]))
colors = mapper.to_rgba(normaldata)
# this is supposed to map the values to their corresponding colors, returns R, G, B, A values
x = np.linspace(0, len(normaldata), len(normaldata))
plt.plot(x, colors)
plt.show()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to create an image. This can be done via `imshow`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# some data
data = np.atleast_2d(np.sin(np.sqrt(np.linspace(1,250,250)))*34)
# plot image
plt.imshow(data, aspect="auto", cmap="bwr")
plt.show()
```

[image]